# How can I force a particular monitor to be the "PC" monitor instead of the "Projector"?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

This has been an ongoing problem of mine for the last few graphics cards and operating systems.

Running Windows 10 (64 bit) with a Radeon RX 480 video card, I have the following to monitors:

1. DVI-to-HDMI connecting to what I call my main monitor, but Windows insists on calling monitor #2.
2. HDMI-to-HDMI connecting to my TV, which I consider my projector monitor, but the computer insists on calling monitor #1.

I used Windows Display settings to identify my PC monitor as the main display, but Windows still insists on calling my PC monitor the projector.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: I think by default, DisplayPort/Mini DisplayPort is first, then HDMI, then DVI, then VGA.  Depending on which ports are used, it should follow this monitor numbering.  You can go to Settings and check screen resolution and make which ever monitor your main display, but the numbering is still the same. So set the DVI-to-HDMI to your TV instead?

Comment: And so when I press Win-P, and I have both monitors on, #2 is the projector, unless #1 is off, in which case #2 is the main display.  I was hoping I was missing something obvious.

Comment: Yeah...try swapping the connection.  DVI-to-HDMI will go to the TV and the HDMI-to-HDMI will go to the main monitor.  Maybe this will help.

Comment: Not an option. I need the projector to have sound, and I don't want to go back to wiring sound.